# CSS Diamond / Triangle shaped divider line / border

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, css-shapes

I have the following gold dividing line I'm trying to create in pure CSS.

[image]

I'm trying to create this with the `transform:scale;` CSS So far I have found the following:

```css
.border_angle {
 border: 50vw solid transparent;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom-color: transparent;
 border-left-color: transparent;
 border-top-color: transparent;

 transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%);
 -o-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%);
 
 position: absolute;
 transform-origin: top center;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 11;
}

.border_angle_gold_l {
 border-left-color: #BE955A;
}

.border_angle_gold-light_r {
 border-right-color: #CCA56B;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 200px;" class="border_angle border_angle_gold_l border_angle_gold-light_r"></div>
```

Essentially, I nearly have it but I just need to reverse the triangles!! I can't figure out how... Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Why in pure CSS?

Comment: It was just I thought CSS would be the least heavy option to achieve this - I didn't want to use a transparent PNG or overcomplicate it with javascript etc (if js would have even been an option?!) - I saw it somewhere else and this is how they have done it

Comment: It's not pure CSS if you're using a dummy div.  You could style the bottom of the header section or the top of the content section. Or if it must be done on a dedicated html element, you could use an `hr` element, since that is semantically more correct than a meaningless empty div.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do this differently with less of code and `linear-gradient`:

```css
.triangle {
  margin-top:100px;
  height:80px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%,#BE955A 51%),
    linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%,#BE955A 51%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%,#CCA56B 51%),
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%,#CCA56B 51%);
  background-position:0 0,0 100%,100% 0,100% 100%;
  background-size:50.3% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
```

Here is another idea using clip-path:

```css
.triangle {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #CCA56B 50%, #BE955A 0); 
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
```

Comment: That's interesting - thanks! It kind of works ok - the only thing is if I leave those options at 51% the middle overlaps a little, but if I change them all to 50%. the tops and bottoms of the triangles are jagged...

Comment: @ShaunTaylor i added anther idea by the way ;) ... yes because gradient is not antialiasing, that's why i made the value bigger than 50%, we should play with them to get the need result with less jag

Comment: Actually, I don't want it to stretch so much so if I make it a fixed width, it fixes the jagged edge issue :) Thanks a lot for this!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try duplicating the div and then adding `translateX` like:

```css
.border_angle {
 border: 50vw solid transparent;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom-color: transparent;
 border-left-color: transparent;
 border-top-color: transparent;
 
 position: absolute;
 transform-origin: top center;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 11;
}

.border_angle_gold_l {
 border-left-color: #BE955A;
}

.border_angle_gold-light_r {
 border-right-color: #CCA56B;
}

.first {
    transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
 -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
 -o-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
 -moz-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
 -ms-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
}

.second {
    transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
 -o-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
 -moz-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
 -ms-transform: scaleY(0.105) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 200px;" class="border_angle border_angle_gold_l border_angle_gold-light_r first"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 200px;" class="border_angle border_angle_gold_l border_angle_gold-light_r second"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I like this approach as it doesn't make the diagonal edges jaggy! However, it adds 3? triangles instead of the 2?

Comment: @ShaunTaylor that's weird, I guess since I only tested here the size of the container makes a difference there, in this case you could still try something like this but playing with the values so you only see 2

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the other good answers:

## The pseudo element / border approach

You can create the triangles with the help of borders and apply it to the pseudo elements [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) of your divider. This reduces your code, you only need one element in your markup and you don't have to use transformations:

```css
.divider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

.divider::before,
.divider::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.divider::before {
  border-right: 250px solid #bf9655;
  left: 0;
}

.divider::after {
  border-left: 250px solid #cda667;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
```

## The SVG approach

As [SVG is widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) now, it is also reasonable to use SVG to create shapes. Here would be a simple example, reducing the code length to a minimum of 141B:

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 24 2">
  <polygon points="0,1 12,0 12,2" style="fill:#bf9655;" />
  <polygon points="12,0 24,1 12,2" style="fill:#cda667;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I kind of like the SVG approach as there aren't any jagged edges! But it's a fixed width, so I'm guessing I'd need to use media queries and specify a set of dimensions for the SVG for each window size? Whereas the other options I can set a max-width container and a 100% width and it will resize automatically.

Comment: Updated my snippet accordingly. With the `viewbox` attribute, you can now apply each width of your choice.